# Makefile rule with percent symbol is not evaluated

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm trying to port linux kernel's kconfig util to my product

while compiling I got next error:

```
make[6]: *** No rule to make target `zconf.tab.c', needed by `zconf.tab.o'.  Stop.
```

I found next rule in Makefile.lib for this file

```
$(obj)/%: $(src)/%_shipped
    $(call cmd,shipped)
```

It looks ok for me and it just works in kernel but not in my product.

Then I added another rule right after previous one.

```
$(obj)/%c: $(src)/%c_shipped
    $(call cmd,shipped)
```

And now it works just fine.

Can someone explain me what's wrong with original rule?

In my case `obj=.` and `src=.` (both = dot). Current dir contains appropriate `*_shipped` file.

Comment: What does the output from `make -d` say when the rules fail in the first case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `$(obj)/%: $(src)/%_shipped` qualifies as a [match-anything pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules). (The manual doesn't mention how targets and prerequisites with with directory components are handled, but it would make sense.)

Note the following in the manual:

> A non-terminal match-anything rule cannot apply to a file name that indicates a specific type of data. A file name indicates a specific type of data if some non-match-anything implicit rule target matches it.

Since there are already built-in implicit rules for creating `.c` files (using parser generators for example), the match-anything rule is never considered.

The reason the error doesn't happen for the kernel makefiles is that they run `make` with `-r`, which eliminates built-in implicit rules. It's done in the top-level makefile by setting the `MAKEFLAGS` variable:

```
# Do not use make's built-in rules and variables
# (this increases performance and avoids hard-to-debug behaviour);
MAKEFLAGS += -rR
```

As a simple experiment, I created a file *test.c_foo* and the following makefile:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -r

%: %_foo
   @echo building
```

`make test.c` without the first line gives

> make: *** No rule to make target 'test.c'.  Stop.

With the first line, it prints "building" instead.

Comment: +1, I had this error but setting the flag on the command line or in the makefile didn't do it for me, I'll just remove the percentage sign now that I know why it's happening.